# Finding the distribution of an almost sure limit of random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_n\rightarrow X$ almost surely. If the limit $F_{X_n}(x)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ is continuous, can we say that $F_{X}(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}(x)$ for all real $x$? Now, I describe my attempt.

Since $X_n\rightarrow X$ almost surely, $X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution. Hence, $F_{X}(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}(x)$ for all points $x$ where $F$ is continuous. However, since $F$ is increasing, it can only have countably many discontinuities. Now, for any $x$, we take a sequence $\{x_m\}$ converging to $x$ from the right such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}$ is continuous at all such $x_m$. Using the right continuity of $F_X$ and the continuity of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}$, we can conclude that $F_{X}(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}F_{X_n}(x)$ for all $x$.

Is this correct?